# Conteúdo gerado por ChatGPT e similares não é permitido no Stack Overflow em Português

Tags: suporte, destaque, comunidade, inteligencia-artificial

Com base no [anuncio original no Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831), o uso de conteúdo gerado pelo ChatGPT foi temporariamente banido da rede na ocasião.

Isso foi adotado também no Stack Overflow em Português pelas razões que seguem:

Em resumo, esta rede foi projetada com um critério de qualidade e autenticidade de informação, de forma a ajudar o máximo de pessoas possíveis.

Conteúdo de qualidade precisa ser fundamentado e embasado, preferencialmente didático, e principalmente **correto**. Essas são coisas que tomam tempo, dedicação, e em especial conhecimento do autor para elaborar e compartilhar.

Atualmente o conteúdo gerado por IA (não limitado ao ChatGPT) não tem essas características, e em sua grande maioria é incorreto. Ou pior, em muitos casos, ele *parece* correto, por estar bem escrito, o que é ainda mais perigoso, principalmente para quem não conhece o assunto e não consegue perceber os erros. Esse tipo de conteúdo não é útil e só polui a comunidade com postagens que muitas vezes estão erradas, incompletas, e/ou não possuem fonte e atribuições.

Além disso, respostas geradas por IA são muito fáceis de produzir, enquanto que a curadoria feita por humanos é um processo mais demorado, e em vez de gastarmos tempo revisando tudo, é mais produtivo não permitir que tal conteúdo seja postado.

Conhecimento só se adquire com conteúdo **confiável**. O Stack Overflow em Português é um repositório de conhecimento, então essa restrição se tornou necessária.

Lembrando que quem filtra o conteúdo é a comunidade, e isso não se limita apenas aos moderadores. Você faz parte dessa comunidade e pode contribuir com votos de fechamento e sinalizações úteis.

Se quiser opinar ou questionar algo sobre o assunto, primeiro procure entender [como a comunidade funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help), e **só depois faça o questionamento no [post original](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831)**, por se tratar de algo válido para toda a rede.

Comment: Só não entendi uma coisa: Porque banir temporariamente? Porque não definitivamente? Existe algum planejamento a longo prazo para uso dessa ferramenta pelo Stack Overflow? (ainda não li a postagem por completo)

Comment: @CmteCardeal Está lá no post original: "*What the final policy will be regarding the use of this and other similar tools is something that will need to be discussed with Stack Overflow staff and, quite likely, here on Meta Stack Overflow.*"

Comment: Seria interessante uma integração das ferramentas, um dos grandes problemas hoje do SOpt é o fato de muitas perguntas serem help desk, nesse tipo de pergunta que não é interessante para a comunidade, o usuário poderia ser redirecionado ao ChatGPT (ou alguma outra IA)

Comment: @Costamilam não sei se isso é publicidade ou um tiro no pé do cara que precisa de ajuda. Oferecer a ChatGPT ajuda é muito perigoso pra IA falar algo errado e o cara aprender algo errado. Eu nunca recomendaria um suporte da ChatGPT, já vi ela recomendar coisas nada a ver.

Comment: @CypherPotato esse problema sempre pode acontecer, e não é limitado as IAs apenas, há muito conteúdo ruim na internet, artigos, tutoriais, etc. O ChatGPT é só mais uma fonte, o desenvolvedor deve buscar múltiplas fontes, entender o conteúdo e analisar se aquilo faz sentido pro seu caso. Até mesmo o SOpt tem conteúdo duvidoso, por isso algumas respostas são negativadas e fechadas

Comment: @Costamilam Pelo menos no SOpt o conteúdo ruim dá pra negativar, comentar o que está errado e até mesmo escrever outra resposta mostrando o certo. No ChatGPT não dá, e pra piorar muita gente aceita qq porcaria dele sem questionar. Na minha opinião, integrar o SOpt com qualquer ferramenta que seja pior não faz o menor sentido. Se a pergunta é ruim, que seja fechada, se a resposta é ruim, que receba -1. Quem postou que decida se vai melhorar o post ou procurar outro site (e convenhamos, hj em dia nem precisa sugerir o ChatGPT, todo mundo tá usando pra tudo, até pro que não devia...)

Comment: @hkotsubo muitos iniciantes estão considerando a ChatGPT confiável e as vezes melhores que um experiente na área. Sabe qual é o pior? É que professores de faculdades estão indicando para seus alunos essa IA...

Comment: @Bacco PSC Eles revogaram essa regra, e vários moderadores entraram em greve. Tá uma confusão daquelas, de novo. E desta vez parece que ninguém aqui está ligando (eu inclusive).

Comment: @bfavaretto A regra não foi revogada, o que teve foi uma orientação de não fazer tratamento baseado em "detector de AI", que não é conclusivo por si só (tanto que o post original continua como featured e é [documento oficial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)). edit: recentemente teve outras discussões e o link não vale mais.

Answer (score 8):

Por curiosidade, perguntei à ChatGPT qual a opinião dela sobre o assunto:

> Pergunta: **Por que é interessante o Stack Overflow banir respostas dadas pela ChatGPT?**
>
> O Stack Overflow é uma comunidade dedicada a ajudar os usuários a encontrar soluções para seus problemas de programação, e seu objetivo principal é fornecer informações precisas e úteis para resolver esses problemas. Embora a ChatGPT seja uma ferramenta útil para responder a perguntas de maneira geral, ela não foi especificamente treinada para fornecer respostas para perguntas específicas de programação, e pode não ser capaz de fornecer soluções precisas e relevantes para os problemas apresentados.
>
> Além disso, o Stack Overflow valoriza a contribuição da comunidade e busca incentivar a participação de usuários reais, que possuem conhecimento e experiência em programação. Ao permitir que a ChatGPT responda perguntas, isso poderia desencorajar a participação de usuários reais, o que poderia prejudicar a qualidade das respostas fornecidas no site e afetar a credibilidade da comunidade.
>
> Por essas razões, o Stack Overflow decidiu banir respostas dadas pela ChatGPT e incentivar a participação de usuários reais na comunidade, de modo a garantir que as respostas fornecidas sejam precisas, úteis e relevantes para os problemas apresentados.

Comment: Esse é um exemplo porque o ChatGPT não deveria ser minimamente acreditado. E algumas pessoas vão ler isso e não vão achar os erros. Isso é o mais preocupante.

Comment: Até o próprio ChatGPT é mais sensato que "influencers" de LikedIn (ou pelo menos erra menos que os tais)

Comment: @CmteCardeal mas ainda consegue manter uma definição errônea sobre o SOpt