# Como identificar conteúdo gerado por IA?

Tags: suporte, comunidade, inteligencia-artificial

Recentemente foi [anunciado no Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-na-rede) (e no Stack Overflow) que conteúdo gerado por inteligência artificial, como a ChatGPT, não é permitido na rede.

A minha dúvida é: como podemos identificar conteúdo gerado por IA aqui no site? E após identificar este conteúdo, o que devemos fazer?

Comment: _"O mais indicado do que fazer em identificar casos de conteúdo gerado por IA é sinalizar à um moderador e deixar sua opinião sobre aquele conteúdo."_ Como fazer isso? Seria marcar uma P/R como **Qualidade muito baixa** ou **Precisa de intervenção de moderador**?

Comment: @CmteCardeal isso depende do bom senso. Raramente vai precisar da intervenção de um moderador, sinalizar pro sistema já é suficiente. Dificilmente vai ser uma pergunta usada para IA, mas se for, o fechamento por baixa qualidade deve servir também. O sistema interpreta que o usuário está tendo muito conteúdo fechado e com pouca recepção, e acaba automaticamente limitando suas contas.

Comment: @CmteCardeal Como as respostas geradas por IA costumam ser ruins (ainda não vi um exemplo bom de verdade), faz-se o mesmo que já fazemos quando um humano gera uma resposta ruim: downvote e/ou comentar o que está errado e/ou sinalizar como baixa qualidade. Se vc desconfia que foi gerado por IA, sinalize para a moderação usando o motivo "_Precisa de intervenção de moderador_". Mas vale notar que são ações independentes (tratar respostas ruins, independente de quem fez - IA ou humano - e sinalizar casos suspeitos de ser IA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um dos problemas desde o anúncio é identificar conteúdo gerado por IA muitas vezes que eles podem se misturar entre conteúdo gerado por humanos, mas com algumas observações interessantes feitas pela comunidade acabam auxiliando o processo de identificar conteúdo de GPT e sinalizar aos moderadores.

Nenhum destes itens abaixo é uma regra, ou ao menos sejam totalmente certeiros, no entanto, conteúdo ruim ainda pode ter sido criado por um humano real. Essa lista é baseada em padrões, que posteriormente é possível prever a origem do conteúdo.

## Lista de padrões e sinais de contéudo possivelmente gerado por IA

- Comumente o conteúdo não possui links que apontam para fontes, documentações, manuais ou *fiddles*.
- Comumente o conteúdo não cita autores, não menciona documentações ou tópicos externos.
- É comum ver apenas um ou nenhum pedaço de código na publicação. O contexto é piorado quando o código inclui um "exemplo completo", desde o início até o fim do que a publicação diz.
- Em respostas, é comum a primeira frase da publicação já ser um indicativo de todo o escopo da publicação, e por muitas vezes já entrega a resposta.
- É muito comum o conteúdo incluir informação **falsa** ou **errada**.
- O conteúdo gerado sempre são intrapessoais e estão em terceira-pessoa. Raramente é encontrado indicativos de pronomes (eu, minha experiência, fiz, etc...).
- Não há nenhuma ou alguma opinião, seja para recomendar uma metodologia, solução ou até mesmo apresentar mais de uma solução. A IA costuma ser direta à responder exclusivamente a pergunta e normalmente não apresenta mais de uma solução.
- O conteúdo interpretado por essa [ferramenta gratuita](https://platform.openai.com/ai-text-classifier) indica que *"The classifier considers the text to be **likely** AI-generated."*.

## Outros pontos relevantes para identificar GPT

Um dos pontos que gosto de analisar é olhar o perfil de quem tá publicando respostas geradas por IA. Das poucas vezes que teve casos assim no site, normalmente:

- O usuário pertencia a uma conta nova;
- Mais de uma resposta com estrutura similar era publicada no mesmo dia ou em uma janela de tempo curta ou curtíssima;

Mas claro que isso não é uma regra. Aliás, nenhum destes pontos é uma regra ou algo obrigatório na análise. Eles ajudam a identificar, e quanto mais pontos, maior a chance do conteúdo ser gerado por IA.

Mesmo se o conteúdo não for gerado por IA e ter mais de um ponto mencionado aqui, provavelmente é porque é conteúdo ruim e nós já temos um passo-a-passo para ter uma boa recepção aqui no site [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta?noredirect=1&lq=1), [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?noredirect=1&lq=1), [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7165/baixa-qualidade-em-perguntas-de-novatos?noredirect=1&lq=1), [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/o-que-%c3%a9-o-stack-overflow?noredirect=1&lq=1), [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas?noredirect=1&lq=1) e principalmente [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel?noredirect=1&lq=1).

---

Recentemente também descobri que ela é muito subjetiva ao que você pergunta.

Perguntei para a ChatGPT se propriedades CSS diferenciavam maíusculas de minúsculas e dei o exemplo de `.minha-propriedade` e `.Minha-Propriedade`. Ela disse que não, e que não havia problema escrever propriedades `.assim` que ela seria interpretada como `.ASSIM`.

Estava errado, e logo já percebi que ela estava confundindo porque havia mencionado "propriedades" no começo da pergunta, mas o exemplo que dei foi de um seletor.

Então se você pergunta sobre uma variável, mas usa o termo "constante" (ou qualquer outro), ela irá te responder usando os mesmos termos apresentados brevemente.

Isso pode ser ótimo para identificar quem está usando a ChatGPT, porque se está usando ela, muitas vezes não é programador, e se não é programador, não vai saber responder essas perguntas por si próprio.

## O que fazer em possíveis casos?

O mais indicado do que fazer em identificar casos de conteúdo gerado por IA é sinalizar à um moderador e deixar sua opinião sobre aquele conteúdo.

Se você acredita que aquele conteúdo é ruim e pode prejudicar a comunidade, você já sabe o que pode fazer e seus votos são uma das suas ferramentas disponíveis.

Isso não vale somente para conteúdo gerado por IA, mas conteúdo ruim no geral. O voto é a sua melhor ferramenta, e o sistema interpreta seus votos (e de mais pessoas) e logo toma medidas automáticas.

Fique a vontade para colaborar com mais pontos e observações relevantes neste processo de identificação de IA e juntos vamos continuar tendo uma comunidade com conhecimento limpo, confiável e feito por humanos empenhados (sem bip bop).

Comment: Pra mim, o conteúdo do ChatCPT muitas vezes parece uma redação feita por uma criança: muita repetição e conteúdo raso (com todo respeito às crianças). Ex: "*[assunto] é assim, mas [assunto] pode ser assado. [assunto] tem isso, [assunto] não tem aquilo. [assunto] é legal, etc*". Várias vezes o primeiro parágrafo só repete a pergunta. E o principal, muitas vezes é um conteúdo errado, mas "dito com convicção", e quem não conhece o assunto pode ter a falsa impressão de estar certo (o que também acontece com conteúdo gerado por humanos, claro, mas pra isso temos o downvote)