# Lembrete que não é permitido respostas geradas por IA

Tags: debate, status-revisão, comunidade, inteligencia-artificial

Recentemente vi algo no Stack Overflow e achei muito interessante se tivessemos no nosso site também. Como já definido pela comunidade e anunciado pelo Meta, [não é permitido o uso de IA para gerar respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-na-rede) no site, mas parece que mesmo assim ainda alguns passam pelo filtro da comunidade.

No entanto, acho que esse aviso, como na imagem abaixo, seria bem-vindo na nossa comunidade, mas não sei como é que é feito para implementar isso no nosso site.

O que acham de embutir um aviso desse no nosso site? É complicado? Depende de alguém além de nós?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para ativar esse aviso precisa [disso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8904/137387) onde será ligado o *Learn more*. Depois é só fazer aqui no meta mesmo a solicitação. Ref https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394512/608272

Comment: sou a favor de ambas ações (desta proposta e a do @AugustoVasques) - muito sinceramente, me frustra uma coisa tão básica ter burocracia para implementar. Se o site bane post de AI, que é nosso caso, entendo desnecessário ter que fazer uma "proposta para avisar".